# E2E Testing using cypress - Azure AD Single Sign On

Tags: single-sign-on, cypress, e2e-testing, angular-e2e

I have been trying to achieve end to end testing using cypress in my angular project and is stuck with a single sign-on issue. Please help me with possible approaches.

Briefing:
My Angular application uses Azure AD Microsoft login to authenticate users to use the application. Is there a way to handle this sign on using cypress or is there a way to bypass
sign on completely.

I have already tried the following blogs and still stuck:
https://www.eliostruyf.com/cypress-test-sharepoint-solution-azure-ad-secured-api/  
https://www.techtonic.com/resources/blog/puppeteer-can-fill-in-cypress-gaps  
https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/best-practices.html#Visiting-external-sites  
https://docs.cypress.io/examples/examples/recipes.html#Single-Sign-On

Whenever I use Cypress to navigate to any page in my app(apart from login), it's getting redirected back to the login giving 401.
Is there any solution to bypass the complete login process and continue E2E testing of the whole app using cypress?
If not, how to handle azure AD single sign-on testing with cypress or any other technology?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Logging into Azure Ad with Cypress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64822167/logging-into-azure-ad-with-cypress)